# moments of a Geometric brownian motion using Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Can someone explain me what is wrong in my derivation of the formula for the moments of a GBM using Ito's lemma (I am not interested in other methods) ?
\begin{equation}
dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma XdW_t
\end{equation}
setting $Y=X^n$ we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{dY}{Y}=(n\mu+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\sigma^2t)dt+ n \sigma dW_t
\end{equation}
at this point my book says "the expectation of $Y=X^n$ follows directly:
\begin{equation}
E[X(t)]^n=X(0) \exp{(n\mu+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\sigma^2)}t
\end{equation}
however, when I try to do this step something goes wrong. I start solving for  $Y_t$ in the usual way (taking the logarithm and then computing the differential) and so I obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d\log Y_t& =\frac{1}{Y}dY-\frac{1}{2Y^2}(dY)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{Y} \biggl( (n\mu+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\sigma^2t)Ydt+ n \sigma Y dW_t \biggr)-\frac{1}{2Y^2}n^2 Y^2 \sigma^2 dt \\
& = [ (n\mu+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\sigma^2t)-\frac{1}{2}n^2 \sigma^2 ]dt + n \sigma dW_t 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
As you can see I obtain a $-\frac{1}{2}n^2 \sigma^2$ in the drift that I should not obtain

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
\Bbb E(e^{σ·W_t}) = e^{\frac12σ^2·t}
$$
so that the extra term in the solution formula for $Y_t$ cancels again when taking the expectation.